# Woocommerce. Отсутствует блок с изображением товара

Tags: woocommerce

Добрый день. Проблема вот в чем: при добавлении или редактировании товара в правой колонке должен находиться блок "Изображение товара" (см.скрин). Так вот - он отсутствует. Пробовал деактивировать все плагины, кроме woocommerce, результатов не дало. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: Скрин изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В самом верхнем правом углу страницы есть блок "Настройки экрана". Откройте его - наверняка не отмечен пункт "Изображение товара".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовал уже(( В настройках самого WC не нашел [Скрин ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoA4V.jpg)

Comment: Вижу нестандартный блок "Видео товара". Скорее всего, тема подменяет "Изображение товара" этим полем. Смените на время тему на стандартную и посмотрите на результат.

Comment: Да, со стандартной темой все в норме. Как же теперь вернуть на этой теме изображение товара?

Answer (score -1):

> В чем может быть проблема?

В древнючей кривой теме без поддержки миниатюр/WC.